# Naming a widget to auto-destroy-replace it

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a picture gallery that exists independently in several places within the app. When any of the galleries close, the current picture displayed in it is posted to a central graphics edit area. So the pictures were gridding on top of each other and I was planning to add code to delete the one that was already there when I stumbled on some unexpected behavior that seems to make this unnecessary. When I used the `name` option to give the container a name, instead of gridding a new container and picture on top of the existing one, apparently the old one was destroyed and replaced automatically.

My question is, can I rely on this behavior, or is it some kind of fluke? I can't find any documentation on it. From Fredrick Lundh, one of Tkinter's authors, "If you really need to specify the name of a widget, you can use the name option when you create the widget. One (and most likely the only) reason for this is if you need to interface with code written in Tcl." So I'm worried that I'll be relying on a fluke but so far it's a good fluke because I don't have to figure out how to keep widgets from gridding on top of each other if tkinter is going to auto-destroy the old one for me. It's not that hard but this `name` option thing is easier.

The example shows this behavior in action. If you remove the `name` option from the functions that create the widgets, the widgets grid on top of each other. But with the `name` option used, the widgets replace each other.

```
import tkinter as tk

def create():
    f1 = tk.Frame(root, bg='red', name='exists') #
    f1.grid(column=0, row=0)
    l1 = tk.Label(f1, bg='yellow', text='This is a very long sentence.')
    l1.grid(column=0, row=0)
    count_labels()

def replace():
    f1 = tk.Frame(root, bg='green', name='exists') #
    f1.grid(column=0, row=0)
    l1 = tk.Label(f1, bg='tan', text='short sentence')
    l1.grid(column=0, row=0)
    count_labels()

def count_labels():
    root.update_idletasks()
    for child in root.winfo_children():
        x = child
        print(len(x.winfo_children()))

root = tk.Tk()

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='create', command=create)
b1.grid(column=0, row=1)

b2 = tk.Button(root, text='replace', command=replace)
b2.grid(column=1, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```